# button onclick doesn't work (DELETE), Using DATATABLE

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I'm using jQuery DataTables to display information, but when i click on the Delete button the last does not work, such i am a new developer.
This is my code :

```
var dataTable;
$(document).ready(function () {
    loadDataTable();
});

function loadDataTable(){
    dataTable = $('#DT_load').DataTable({
        "ajax": {
            "url": "/api/book",
            "type": "GET",
            "datatype": "json"
        },
        "columns": [
            { "data": "name", "width": "25%" },
            { "data": "author", "width": "25%" },
            { "data": "isbn", "width": "25%" },
            {
                "data": "id",
                "render": function (data) {
                    return `<div class="text-center">
                        <a href="/BookList/Edit?id=${data}" class="btn btn-success text-white" style='cursor:pointer; width:70px;'>
                            Edit
                        </a>
                        &nbsp;
                        <button class="btn btn-danger text-white" style='cursor:pointer; width:70px;'
                         onclick=Delete('/api/book?id='+${data})>

                            Delete
                        </button>
                        </div>`;
                }, "width":"40%"
            }
        ],
        "language": {
            "url": "js/Arabic.json"

        },
        "width":"100%"

    })
}
```

Thank you .

Comment: What you mean by "_the last does not work_"? What is the current behaviour? What is the expected behaviour?

Comment: i mean the Delete button 
<button class="btn btn-danger text-white" style='cursor:pointer; width:70px;'
                         onclick=Delete('/api/book?id='+${data})>

                            Delete
                        </button>

Answer (score 0):

Set `type="button"` for your button. Then pass id to the Delete Function.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger text-white" style='cursor:pointer; width:70px;' onclick="Delete(data)">
```

At the end use ajax to call your Delete action :

```
function Delete(id) {  
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: '@Url.Action("Delete")', //delete action
      data: JSON.stringify({ id: id }), //use id here
      contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
      success: function (data) {

      },
      error: function (error) {

      }
    });
}
```